# Numerical label with certain number of digits (regular expressions in Bash)

Tags: bash, formatting

In a bash script, I have a numerical variable that I will use as a label to address a file. For instance:

```
label=23
filename=file.$label.txt
```

But there is a convention that the label has a constant number of digits, say five. So my label should be 00023. What regular expression (or other method) can I use to convert any number to the desired format? Here are some use cases:

```
label=1 => filename=file.00001.txt
label=23 => filename=file.00023.txt
label=555 => filename=file.00555.txt
```

The label is always smaller than 99999

Comment: `printf -v filename 'file.%05d.txt' "$label"`?